# adding dynamic css to menu and homepage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am adding a class `"current_page_item"` to current page based on the url `<a href"">` value.  My home page `<a href="myurl/">Home</a>` all others have values  eg. `<a href="myurl/nom">Nom</a>`

The menu structure is like

```
<nav id="main-menu">
   <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
     <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0">
      <a href="myurl/">Home</a>
      </li>
  <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0">
      <a href="myurl/page2">Page2</a>
      </li>
  <li class="menu-item-simple-parent menu-item-depth-0">
      <a href="myurl/page3">Page3</a>
      </li>
...................and so on
</ul></nav>
```

This is the Script I have come up so far

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var pnom = @(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["nom"]).ToLowercase();
            jQuery('ul.menu li.menu-item-simple-parent.menu-item-depth-0 a')
               .removeClass('current_page_item')
               .filter(function (index) {
                   return jQuery(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf(pnom) != -1;
               })
               .addClass('current_page_item');
        });
</script>
```

My problem is how to accommodate the homepage's null exception. I want a condition in the code that will still add the class to the  homepage though the pnom value is null.
Please help.

Comment: `var pnom = @(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["nom"] ?? 'myurl/').ToLowercase();` or `var pnom = @(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["nom"]).ToLowercase(); || 'myurl/'`  should work

Comment: Thanks I think the problem is in the javascript logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var pnom = @(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["nom"] ?? "").toLowercase();
```

sets a default value when `RouteData.Values["nom"]` is `null`, or even better,

```
(function($){
    $(function () {
        var pnom = "myurl/"+"@((HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["nom"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower())";
        $('ul.menu li.menu-item-simple-parent.menu-item-depth-0 a')
            .removeClass('current_page_item')
            .filter(function (index) {
            return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pnom;
        })
        .addClass('current_page_item');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/yrt02zmx/1)

Comment: thanks I have tried was getting undefined exception at the return jquery line for all pages not only the homepage

Comment: the undefined error was due to you were getting `var pnom = .toLowerCase()` from your c# code. Wrapping the code with quotes produces `var pnom = "".toLowerCase()` which is valid javascript code.

Comment: the javascript part works: http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/yrt02zmx/ what result you're looking for?

Comment: thanks  that is just what I want but the problem is the homepage which has no value i   want the class to append as you have done.  For some reason there is this need to change or jquery $ markups to jQuery before any customised scripts works on this template.  Do you know how to reset to default - where I will not have to change $ to jQuery

Comment: you can use a closure, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/yrt02zmx/1/

Comment: Great! I updated the answer partially (w/o format), I'll fix it later.